# Add structure(s) to QList in for-loop

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I fill a structure in a loop and per loop i want to have a new instance (copy) in a Qlist of this instance.

I read data out of a (xml)file and will store the data in that QList.

After eg. 4 loops, the QList contains only one structure ...

```
typedef struct structure_Anf
{

public:

    typedef struct structure_Art
    {
    public:
        QString Art = "";
    }
    structure_Art_t;

    QString Num = "";

    QList <structure_Art_t> ArtList;

}
structure_Anf_t;


QList <structure_Anf_t> FullAnfList; // holds the full list of structures

structure_Anf_t struc_act_Anf; // holding actual used instance of structure



void test
{

    for ( int i=0; i < 5; i++) // add some data
    {
        struc_act_Anf = {};

        struc_act_Anf.Num = "foo" + i;

        structure_Anf_t::structure_Art_t struc_new_Art;

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) // add some data to Art
        {
            struc_new_Art.Art = "bar" + x;

            ArtList.append (struc_new_Art);
        }

        FullAnfList.append (struc_act_Anf);
    }

}
```

Edit: Some minor changes on the code.

As i wrote above, after i-times-loop, FullAnfList.count() = 1 and not 5 as expected.

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code you are currently using? Compiler errors? Wrong output?

Comment: In C++ the structure or class tag is also a type-name and can be used without the use of `typedef`.

Comment: As for your problem, please try to create a [mcve] to show us, preferably one which replicates the problem you have. If nothing else, attempting to create such an example often could help you find the problem yourself. Also please read (or refresh) about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: That's not even valid C++.

Comment: If it is not "valid c++" then please show me the right way to Valid-C++.
It is not an helpful answer for a beginner.
Sorry,

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Qt , I convert it to Std c++ it works properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
using QString = std::string;

template <typename T>
using QList = std::list<T, std::allocator<T>>;

typedef struct structure_Anf
{
public:
    typedef struct structure_Art
    {
    public:
        QString Art = "";

    }
    structure_Art_t;

    QString Num = "";

    QList<structure_Art_t> ArtList;
}
structure_Anf_t;

QList <structure_Anf_t> FullAnfList;

structure_Anf_t struc_act_Anf; // holding actual used instance of structure
void test()
{
    for (auto i : { 1,2,3,4,5,6 })
    {
        struc_act_Anf = {};

        struc_act_Anf.Num = "foo";
        structure_Anf_t::structure_Art_t struc_new_Art;

        for (auto i : { 1,2,3,4,5,6})
        {
            struc_new_Art.Art = "bar";

            struc_act_Anf.ArtList.push_back(struc_new_Art);
        }

        FullAnfList.push_back(struc_act_Anf);
    }
}

int main()
{
    test();
    std::cin.get();
}
```